# Trigger functions with dropdown menus

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple script to sort columns:

```
 function sortbytype() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("$A$26:AI")
    .sort({
        column: 1,
        ascending: true
    });
}


function sortbytime() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("$A$26:AI")
    .sort({
        column: 2,
        ascending: true
    });
}
```

I have a dropdown in cell A1 with the two options:

- Sort by time
- Sort by type

I would like to trigger either function when the option in A1 dropdown is modified. I know it's basic, but I really struggle with the syntax...

Any help would be very appreciated...

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
I have added one dropdown list on cell A1.

Which contains two following values:

- Sort by time
- Sort by type

Here is the App script code.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newsheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var id = newsheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

  if(id=='Sort by type')
  {
    sortbytype();
  }else{
    sortbytime();
  }
}
function sortbytype() {
   //Do something
  Browser.msgBox('SortBytype Function called ', Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
function sortbytime() {
   //Do something
  Browser.msgBox('SortBytime function called', Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
```

here is the reference link:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: @tehhowch ... thanks, it was my mistake. Answer edited.